# Encrypt Zip Files created with Android Logback

Tags: android, encryption, logback

I have a requirement to encrypt the internal Zip files created using the Logbak-Android library: https://github.com/tony19/logback-android

Note: The requirement is to encrypt the entire zip file that is automatically created by the Logback library and not to encrypt each line entry separately.

Is there a way to do so using the Logback API?

If not, is there a way to monitor the target folder of those files and perhaps to encrypt the once they are created?